# Fast, scalable string lookup

Tags: scaling, lookup

I have a set of 5 million strings. These are currently stored in a single column MySQL table. My application has to perform lookups and check if a given string is in the set. This can of course be done with a HashSet (in Java). But instead of building a custom solution, I was wondering if there are any existing, widely used, proven solutions that do this? It seems like a common scenario. The solution should be scalable (the set might increase beyond 5 million), have failover (so probably distributed) and perform well under a huge number of requests. Any suggestions?

Update: My app can also query to check if a given set of strings is present in the global (the 5 million one) set.

Comment: Perhaps I'm not understanding what you mean by "perform lookups" and "check if a given string is in the set" - isn't this simply what an SQL select statement is for? Failover and scaling are also more or less normal RDBMS features.

Comment: Tries are used for fast string lookup. They are much more memory efficient than hashtables/hashsets, and not much slower.

Comment: @Sorpigal: Yes, but normal RDBMS queries are not fast enough. I've also updated my question with the exact scenario. Hope that clears it up.

Answer (score 1):

You can try [Trie](http://code.google.com/p/trie/) or [Patricia-trie](http://code.google.com/p/patricia-trie/).The second is more memory efficient.Also [here](http://sujitpal.blogspot.com/2007/02/three-autocomplete-implementations.html) you can find a comparison of 2 data structures [Trie,TreeSet],In-memory database and their performance.

Comment: the message in front of the Trie project is not very encouraging - "Note to any visitors, this is fine SAMPLE code, but not production code. It was written by an inexperienced programmer (me at the time) in one evening. "

Answer (score 1):

Try [memcached](http://memcached.org/), a high-performance, distributed memory object caching system.  You lookup using key/value hashes.  [Facebook uses memcached](http://www.facebook.com/note.php?note_id=39391378919) as do many other highly scalable sites.  Need to store more strings?  Just add more memcached instances to the cluster.  Plus you can use in a 2-tier caching setup where you first query memcached, if cache miss then query the full database.

Have you considered adding [column indexing](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/column-indexes.html) to your MySQL database?  Hash, b-tree and r-tree are supported.

MySQL can also be [replicated and clustered](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/ha-overview.html) for high scalability.

Comment: It's a distributed hashing system for efficient key/value lookups.

Answer (score 0):

While a Trie might be the best solution, binary search on the sorted list of strings should also perform well run time wise.